# Why am I getting a syntax error when I check my interface? Trying to make a MAC changer for Linux with Python/argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, mac-address

I'm making a python 3.x program that runs the commands for changing the MAC in Linux every couple of minutes (as one of its various functions). I double checked and I have ifconfig installed, so that's not the issue. Here's the section causing me grief:

```
import sys
import subprocess
import argparse
import random
import time
import re

def macfunc():

    def get_args():
            #Get interface stuff
            prsr = argparse.ArgumentParser()
            prsr.add_argument("-i","--interface",dest="interface",help="Name of interface.")
            options = prsr.parse_args()
            if options.interface:
                return options.interface
            else:
                prsr.error("syntax error")
        def changer(interface, new_mac_address):
            #Does the terminal commands for changing the MAC
            subprocess.call(["sudo","ifconfig",interface,"down"])
            subprocess.call(["sudo","ifconfig",interface,"hw","ether",new_mac_address])
            subprocess.call(["sudo","ifconfig",interface,"up"])
        def get_random_mac():
            #Randomizes MAC
            charset="0123456789abcdef"
            random_mac="00"
            for i in range(5):
                random_mac += ":" + \
                              random.choice(charset) \
                              + random.choice(charset)
                return random_mac
        def get_original(interface):
            #Holds the current MAC for restoration purposes
            output=subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig",interface])
            return re.search("\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w",str(output)).group(0)
    
        #Now let's do the magic and change the mac every 2 minutes
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            print("Initializing MAC scrambler. Generating new MAC every 2 minutes.")
            sleeper=120
            interface=get_args()
            current_mac=get_original(interface)
            try:
                while True:
                    random_mac=get_random_mac()
                    change_mac(interface,random_mac)
                    new_mac_info=subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig",interface])
                    if random_mac in str(new_mac_info):
                        print("New MAC:",random_mac,end=" ")
                        sys.stdout.flush()
                        time.sleep(sleeper)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                change_mac(interface,current_mac)
                print("Original MAC restored. Terminating scrambling.")

macfunc()
```

Whenever I run it, I get my syntax error message. I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm missing. It's probably something incredibly stupid on my part. Help would be smashing.

Comment: Is that the format the code was in? Python is very sensitive to indentation so I think just fixing that so it is all uniform would help.

Comment: @Justin Ah, you're right about the indentation. That's not how it was in my code; copy pasting it here messed it up somewhat. I've fixed the above snippet now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went about it a different way and achieved the same desired result!

```
import time
import subprocess
import random
import time
from getmac import get_mac_address as gma


#Look after the original MAC
original=(gma())
#Randomize a new address
charset="0123456789abcdef"
randommac="00"
for i in range(5):
    randommac += ":" +\
                    random.choice(charset)\
                    + random.choice(charset)
#do the terminal commands
def subproc():
    subprocess.call(["sudo","ifconfig","wlp3s0","down"])
    subprocess.call(["sudo","ifconfig","wlp3s0","hw","ether",randommac])
    subprocess.call(["sudo","ifconfig","wlp3s0","up"])
    
subproc()    
print("Your MAC has been cheesed. New MAC:" + randommac)
print("The new MAC will expire in 60 seconds and be reverted.")
print("KEEP THIS PROGRAM OPEN.")
time.sleep(60)
subprocess.call(["sudo","ifconfig","wlp3s0","down"])
subprocess.call(["sudo","ifconfig","wlp3s0","hw","ether",original])
subprocess.call(["sudo","ifconfig","wlp3s0","up"])
print("Old MAC restored:" + original)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have not used proper indentation. Instead of using argparse in this type of simple program, I recommend you to do that with your own function. And, to get the current MAC address you can simply run this command `cat /sys/class/net/{interface}/address` instead of using re.

```
import subprocess
import random
import time
import sys

def elementAfter(lst,element):  
    try:
        elementIndex = lst.index(element)

        elementAfter = lst[elementIndex + 1]
        return elementAfter
    except ValueError:
        return False

def change_mac(interface, new_mac_address):
    #Does the terminal commands for changing the MAC
    subprocess.call(["sudo","ifconfig",interface,"down"])
    subprocess.call(["sudo","ifconfig",interface,"hw","ether",new_mac_address])
    subprocess.call(["sudo","ifconfig",interface,"up"])

def get_random_mac():
    #Randomizes MAC
    charset="0123456789abcdef"
    random_mac="00"
    for i in range(5):
        random_mac += ":" + \
                      random.choice(charset) \
                      + random.choice(charset)
        return random_mac

def get_original(interface):
    #Holds the current MAC for restoration purposes
    currentMac = subprocess.run(f'cat /sys/class/net/{interface}/address', shell=True, capture_output=True)
    return currentMac.stdout.decode("utf-8").rstrip()

#Now let's do the magic and change the mac every 2 minutes
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Initializing MAC scrambler. Generating new MAC every 2 minutes.")
    sleeper=120
    interface=elementAfter(sys.argv,"-i") or elementAfter(sys.argv,"--interface")
    current_mac=get_original(interface)
    try:
        while True:
            random_mac=get_random_mac()
            change_mac(interface,random_mac)
            new_mac_info=subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig",interface])
            if random_mac in str(new_mac_info):
                print("New MAC:",random_mac,end=" ")
                sys.stdout.flush()
                time.sleep(sleeper)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        change_mac(interface,current_mac)
        print("Original MAC restored. Terminating scrambling.")
```

Comment: Hi, this returns the following error: 

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1482, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not bool

Comment: I am not getting any errors. Are you sure you are running the above code properly?

Comment: I'm just opening a new file and trying to run this snippet in isolation. Is that what you did?